# how can i read an excel file from given path in .net

Tags: asp.net, .net

public Task Signature(int approverId, string attachmentPath)
{

```
    string filePath = attachmentPath;

    string signPath = @"C:\path\to\image.jpg";

    return Task.FromResult(0);
```

}

in here attachmentPath is an string variable thats a excel file  and signPath is a path of image  how can i add the sign image into the attachmentPath excel in .net zero

import an image into excel in .net